# Random cluster generation

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I want to generate clusters of data points drawn from multivariate Gaussian distribution.

I want all the clusters to have the same co-variance matrix. I am using the command genRandomClust from the clusterGeneration package for this.

But unfortunately the above command generates clusters with different covariance matrix. Can some one point me at a command or package that can achieve this objective?

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Here we are drawing samples from bi-variate normal random distribution.

```
library(MASS)
Sigma <- matrix(c(10,3,3,2),2,2) # start with a fixed 2x2 covariance matrix, or generate it randomly
Sigma
datapoints <- mvrnorm(n = 1000, rep(0, 2), Sigma) # draw 1000 MVN samples with cov matrix Sigma, with mean c(0, 0) or use some random mean vector
var(datapoints) # notice that the covariance matrix for the datapoint generated is slightly different from Sigma
datapoints <- mvrnorm(n = 1000, rep(0, 2), Sigma, empirical = TRUE)
var(datapoints) # here the covariance matrix for the datapoint generated is exactly equal to Sigma
```